# How to import Unicode csv file?

Tags: r, csv, unicode, csv-import

I have unicode csv file:

```
LabelName,Label1,Label2,SpeciesLabel,Group,Subgroup,Species
التسمية 1,Group 1,Subgroup 1,Species 1,1,1,1
التسمية 2,Group 1,Subgroup 1,Species 1,1,1,1
التسمية 3,Group 1,Subgroup 1,Species 1,1,1,1
```

I want to read it into R, and I used this command:

```
Data = read.csv("Data.csv", encoding="UTF-8", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

But I got this error:

> ```
> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>   empty beginning of file
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
>   invalid input found on input connection 'Data.csv'
> 2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
>   line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
> 3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
>   incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'Data.csv'
> ```

How can I read unicode (with arabic letters) csv file in R.

Thanks!

Comment: How sure are you that the file is encoded as UTF-8? What OS and R version are you using?

Comment: I checked it in Notepad++. 
OS - Windows 7, R - 3.1.0

Comment: When I tested, `Data = read.csv("Data.csv", encoding="UTF-8")` seemed to work. But while the default `print.data.frame` doesn't seem to render the correct encoding, just looking at `Data$LabelName` does show the proper character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file using `readLines` with the argument `warn = FALSE`, then execute `read.csv` with `text` argument as below:

```
arabic <- readLines("arabic.csv", warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
Data = read.csv(text = arabic)
str(Data)
```

Output:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ X.U.FEFF.LabelName: Factor w/ 3 levels "التسمية 1","التسمية 2",..: 1 2 3
 $ Label1            : Factor w/ 1 level "Group 1": 1 1 1
 $ Label2            : Factor w/ 1 level "Subgroup 1": 1 1 1
 $ SpeciesLabel      : Factor w/ 1 level "Species 1": 1 1 1
 $ Group             : int  1 1 1
 $ Subgroup          : int  1 1 1
 $ Species           : int  1 1 1
```